# ngIf angular and getting rid of components in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to get rid of my header and footer components in just one specific component and don't know how to go about it. I am treating the app component as the index.html component. When I create a new component, these are always there and I need to figure out how to make it so my new component is blank.

Comment: Megan add alittle more of context to the problem it could be code or something to understand you issue better

Answer (score 2):

You can watch router events in Angular and execute something based on the route.

Example:
You can implement this in your app component.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.router.events.forEach((event: NavigationEnd) => { // fires on each route change
     if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       this.routeParam = event.url; // routeParam is a variable.
     }
     if (this.routeParam === '/') {
       // do something
     } else if (this.routeParam === '/login') {
       // do something
       // you can store a boolean in a service and use it to hide components.
       this.someService.myBoolean = true;
     } else {
       // do something
     }
   })
 }
```

In the UI you can use that boolean.

```
<myComponent *ngIf="!someService.myBoolean"><!-- someService should be 
  public -->
  <!-- component you want to hide -->
</myComponent>
```